# pam_ldap: how to hide password hashes in getent output

Tags: pam, ldap, nsswitch

My question is similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329938/getent-shadow-shows-password-hashes-for-some-users). I use **pam_ldap** for users auth. `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file contains:

```
passwd:         files ldap
group:          files ldap
shadow:         files ldap
```

All seems to be OK, but I need to hide password hashes of LDAP users in `getent passwd` output.

1. I have read [man 5 pam_ldap](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_ldap) and didn't find any useful parameter for `/etc/ldap.conf` file.
2. I read about `sssd`, `nslcd` and find `enumerate` option. It useful but I don't want install any of these services for now.

Is it possible to hide password hashes if I use **pam_ldap**?

---

Example of user `tester`:

```
dn: cn=tester,ou=users,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixAccount
cn: tester
gidNumber: 10000
homeDirectory: /home/tester
sn: Tester
uid: tester
uidNumber: 10000
loginShell: /bin/bash
userPassword: {CRYPT}$1$......
```

My openldap access configuration:

```
access to attrs=userPassword
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by users none

access to * by * read
```

My pam_ldap configuration:

```
uri     ldap://my_host
base    dc=example,dc=org
binddn  cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
bindpw  myPass
ldap_version    3
port    389
scope   one
timelimit       30
bind_timelimit  10
bind_policy     soft
nss_connect_policy      persist
idle_timelimit  3600
nss_paged_results       yes
pagesize        1000
pam_filter      objectclass=posixAccount
pam_login_attribute     uid
pam_lookup_policy       yes
pam_password    md5
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers      root
nss_schema      rfc2307bis
nss_base_passwd ou=users,dc=example,dc=org?one
nss_base_shadow ou=users,dc=example,dc=org?one
nss_base_group  ou=groups,dc=example,dc=org?sub
ssl     no
TLS_REQCERT     allow
```

Comment: I don't think that pam_ldap is responsible for this, but your LDAP setup. Can you post all `objectClass` of a sample user? My first guess would be that they don't have `objectClass: shadowAccount`.

Comment: Also you might want to check your [access directive](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) if non-root users can see the password.

Comment: @Stefan I've just add additional information. Yes, user account don't have `objectClass: shadowAccount`.

Comment: What's your [pam_password](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_ldap) setting? With the `clear` and `exop` protocols the password should not be hashed on the client but rather send to the ldap server, with `crypt` the password is hashed locally. However, this settings affects only passwords that have been changed.

Comment: @Stefan I've just added ldap_conf.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use *ldap* for the *shadow* map. This is not needed at all because even the old *pam_ldap* can check the user's password via LDAP simple bind request and thus does not need to have read access to a password hash.

Also consider to use [sssd](https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/) or [nss-pam-ldapd](https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/) (also known as *nslcd*) because these decouple the LDAP connections from the processes using the PAM stack.